# Keep Jquery animation from occurring unless the event lasts n milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would do it, but it only delays the animation.

`$("#searchsubmit").hover(
function () { $("#quicksearchtip").delay(100).slideDown("slow"); },
 function () { $("#quicksearchtip").delay(100).slideUp("slow"); });`

I don't want the event to fire if the user happens to accidentally pass the cursor over the element for a few milliseconds.

I want it to only occur when they hover over the element.  It's very annoying when the cursor touches the element even for a split second the animation fires even after the mouse has left the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`hoverIntent` plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Comment: Your solution did work. I will be using this library to solve my issue.  However, in regards to adding yet another library to by site, *groans*

Comment: @Doug: Feel free to rewrite the plugin yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may ad a `.stop(true)` before both of the `.delay()` to empty the animation queue, so on quick mouse out, the delayed action will be removed.